# How can I perform SQL Count with ESP32 SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, arduino, esp32

I have spent ages searching for an answer to this, but i can't quite get my head around it.

Basically.I have a sqlite db on a sd card connected to a esp32. SQLite works perfectly and will return when using the standard sample code. For example:

```
rc = db_exec(db2, "Select * from domain_rank where domain between 'google.com' and 'google.com.z'");
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
sqlite3_close(db1);
sqlite3_close(db2);
return;
}`
```

this looks at a "db_exec" function in the sketch then passes it to a "callback" function. Is there a way to do without this? All I want to do is count the number of records in a select statement.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I may have found a solution

Putting it here just in case anyone else is interested.

```
 String sql = "Select count(*) from surnames where name = 'MICHELLE'";
 rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db1, sql.c_str(), 1000, &res, &tail);
 if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
      String resp = "Failed to fetch data: ";
      Serial.println(resp.c_str());
      return;
  }
 while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW) {
      rec_count = sqlite3_column_int(res, 0);
 }

      Serial.println(rec_count);
```

can't quite get my head around what the while loop is doing counting the cells, i thought the sql count* query would just return an int value I could use directly. So I'm still a little confused.

Comments would be welcomed! If anyone has any better ideas?

Thanks

Andrew